# Codekit files not showing at localhost... Chrome cannot connect to server

Tags: localhost, codekit

Running Codekit on OSX 10.8.4.

I can drag the file into a browser and see reloads take place on save. If I try to access files at localhost, the browser tells me it cannot connect.

In other words, this works:

```
file:///Users/me/Desktop/rubydev/susy/index.html
```

but this does not:

```
http://localhost/index.html
```

Any ideas about fixing this?

Edit: I also tried

```
localhost/
localhost/susy/index.html
```

[image: Here's a screenshot of my codekit screen]

[image: and setup dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeKit 1.x does not have a server built-in to it and, thus, will not serve pages. In the demo videos on the website, I'm running MAMP in the background, which is set to host a given folder at `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` (which maps to "localhost").

You can use MAMP or you can set up a server with Node.js, Ruby or the Apache stack built-in to OS X itself.

Comment: Thank you! Will code kit run .erb files / execute partials etc?

Comment: Nope. For that you'd need a Ruby server.

Comment: Any recommendations? I imagine this is a common development pattern.